Ascertaining sub-probabilities using re-sampling of the data. Multivariate convergence?

I am trying to compute a payout for an online game that has the following information:

40% chance of a loss with value -2
10% chance of a loss with value -1
remaining 50% chance with four potential non-negative payouts of 0, 2, 14, and 62.

Current initial GUESSES as to the TRUE probability based on basic analysis of some 150 observations:

$P_1 \approx 20.5\%$ with no gain or loss, a value of 0.
$P_2 \approx 28.5\%$ with a gain of value 2.
$P_4 \approx 0.8\%$ with a gain of value 14.
$P_6 \approx 0.2\%$ with a gain of value 62.

NOTE:  $P_1 + P_2 + P_4 + P_6 = 50\%$
I have done some initial sampling and show the results highlighted in greenish with blue number values.

The 40%, 10%, 50% represent TRUE values, and you can see my basic sample summary does not align perfectly with 40% (38.10) nor 10% (8.84).
I could resample different subsets of the data to create a converging probability.  Since this is multivariate (four probabilities constrained to sum to 50%), I could use some advice.
I can certainly collect a bit more data.
Ultimately, the goal is to ascertain if the game is perfectly fair (payout = 0) or biased in the positive or negative direction.  If negative, the house wins.  If positive, I could win.
How to find the TRUE values of the four unknown probabilities by resampling data to allow CLT convergence?  That is, find $P_1, P_2, P_4, P_6$
These are independent events, IID.
$P_1$ and $P_2$ are about equal to each other, I do not know which is larger.  $P_4$ is much smaller, and $P_6$ is even smaller still.

Resampling from the data is useful, but it cannot provide you with more information about the values themselves. For that, you need more data.

@GuillaumeDehaene Yes, especially since the sample of data does NOT yet have the rare event $P_6$
